# Tips for proper row_number use

Tags: sql, rank

Is there anyone that could help me with creating 'SORT' column.

Here are two examples, how this should work.

Notice that two last rows in second table, are numered as 4 and 5 because type column is changed to 'k' while number is new and date is the same.

Example 1

```
       date number  type    sort
        2012-03-23  3660    d   1
        2015-06-01  1890    k   2
        2015-06-02  8370    k   3
        2015-06-11  4345    d   4
        2015-06-11  4345    d   5
        2015-06-11  4345    d   6
        2015-06-11  4345    d   7
        2015-06-11  4345    d   8
        2015-06-11  4345    d   9
        2015-06-11  3534    k   10
        2015-06-11  3534    k   11
```

Example 2

```
    date    number  type    sort
    2012-03-23  3660    d   1
    2015-06-01  1890    k   2
    2015-06-02  8370    k   3
    2015-06-11  4345    k   4
    2015-06-11  4345    k   5
    2015-06-11  4345    k   6
    2015-06-11  4345    k   7
    2015-06-11  4345    k   8
    2015-06-11  4345    k   9
    2015-06-11  3534    k   4
    2015-06-11  3534    k   5
```

Comment: Please attempt to explain the logic for the column.

Comment: Firstly it should be sorted by the date. IF date, type and number is diffrent than the previous one we should add +1 to sort. But if type and date is the same, but number has changed we must put first sort number for this particular date (4 in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a strange requirement, but here's the solution:

```
select date, number, type, dense_rank() over(order by date, type asc, rank asc) rank2 from (
select row_number() over (partition by date, number, type order by date asc,type desc) rank, * from testTable
) a order by date, number desc, rank2 asc
```

And the sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ad7d/15

Comment: Yea, I know its strange, sorry. Thanks for reply, but it is not right, because if you change type to 'd' for rows with 4345 it won't return 'sort' column like in example 1 :(

Comment: Right, had a small issue.  Fixed now.

Comment: Great! Thank you, you are my hero :)